# When you do "apt-get install" where are the .deb files stored?

Tags: linux, debian, packages, apt-get, deb

I am trying to copy all of the packages I have installed on one Debian machine to another Debian machine without doing another `apt-get install` and downloading all of the package all over again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They're stored in:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/
```

unless you've issued a:

```
apt-get clean
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So, let's say if I copied the files to another machines, what's the easiest way to install all of them?

Comment: Assuming that all the dependencies are satisfied: `dpkg -i *.deb`.

Comment: This is just fine, manual way, well doable on dislocated systems, e.g. without network connection. If the machines are connected (mostly preferred on local network) there are more convenient automatic ways to achieve this, see my answer below about apt proxy.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you just need:

> apt-get download mypackage1 mypackage2

it will download given *.deb files to the current directory. No need for root.

Answer (score 1):

If you had already issued

```
apt-get clean
```

you can take a look at [these pages](http://alfik-fik.com/zcvisitor/3a695a9f-5890-11eb-84ce-1206228a0cb1/72092e88-2c53-401c-b988-51ef43ce1034?campaignid=b16698b0-0d5e-11eb-8341-0a52992aaad9) to [learn about replicating](https://web.archive.org/web/20120614225859/http://chosencollective.com:80/technology/replicate-migrate-ubuntu-packages-apt-get) the same package configuration on the other machine

Comment: both links are now gone, any other source for the info?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a package proxy, we use [approx](http://www.debianadmin.com/upgrade-multiple-debian-systems-with-approx.html)

Then the real repository servers are specified in the approx.conf, like:

```
debian         http://ftp.debian.org/debian
security       http://security.debian.org/debian-security
volatile       http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile
```

In all machines you want to install just place the following to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://<hostname>:9999/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://<hostname>:9999/security/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
etc.
```

When first machine is downloading the packages, they go from the internet and are stored in the cache of approx. All other machines download the packages from the cache directly.